# How to detect if the user have come from external link?

Tags: ember.js

Is there a way to distinguish access through external link (e.g. from history, or from other site) or access by link from other page of the same app in `beforeModel` handler?

Here is my case:

1. If user accesses my app by direct link and requests route requiring authenticated user, I make a transition to index route and show popup with an authorization form.
2. If user is already on my site and trying to access the requested route requiring authenticated user, I abort transition and show the popup on a previous page.
3. I have no separate page for authentication.

**My current work around** is to check some strange private property called `sequence` of transition object which has been passed to `beforeModel` handler, if `transition.sequence === 0`, then user came from "outside", otherwise user follow by link "inside" my app.

*I think this is a bad way to achieve the goal, core developers can remove `sequence` property any time.*

So, **is there any clean way to distinguish whether current route was requested from "outside" or "inside" of my app?**

I'll appreciate any help, thanks!

P.S. **EmberJS v1.10.0**

P.S.S. Sorry for my English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid using an internal call you could keep track of the history in the application route something like this [Implementing a "conditional" back button in ember.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228464/implementing-a-conditional-back-button-in-ember-js)

But in your router would probably be better since controllers are going away soonish.

You could probably use http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#event_didTransition

UPDATE after chatting

Logic for counting, aborting, etc transitions can be done in the willTransition action in application route http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/preventing-and-retrying-transitions/

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but how these links help me? P.S. I'm already using authentication abstraction (https://github.com/Vestorly/torii).

Comment: Hmm I could be misunderstanding, my thought was that you don't need to check if someone accessed via a direct link you can just check check your auth service directly to see if the user is logged in.

Comment: No, I need a way to detect access my app through external link

Comment: I updated my answer but then I read over your thing again.  I see what you're trying to do.  If I may ask a silly question but would it be easier to just redirect the user to the route they are trying to goto after authentication and if route is invalid redirect to root rather than root on page refresh or direct linking to a non index route.

Comment: Ok updated one more time to answer your question better.

Comment: No, I want to distinguish two different situations: 1) user come from another site by link http://app.com/profile (directly to profile route); 2) he followed http://app.com and by clicking internal page link came to http://app.com/profile. That is simple description of my problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73446/discussion-between-varblob-and-glagola).